# My language is English and my question is based on wanting to shorten a compliment I plan on giving a friend

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests

What is a single word that can explain somebody who takes care of their responsibilities, is reliable, and a positive influence?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: What about 'role model'?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use words such as "dependable" or "dedicated". You can also look it up in a [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/) or online!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome here. Answers that rely on the I word hint at opinions, not, well, answers that are **answers** with authority. The two adjectives you offer are just right.